# How to view javascript generated html for Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am looking for a way in IE to view the html source generated from jQuery code.
Ex.
HTML:

```
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
```

jquery:

```
    var wrapper = $("myDiv");
    var generated = $("<div>Hello world</div>");
    wrapper.append(generated);
```

I'd like to be able to examine and hopefully tweak the source generated by appending the generated element, not in Chrome or Firefox, but in IE 8 (where the problem is).  I think that IE Developer Tools only shows the downloaded source, not what is generated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try going to the HTML tab in IE developer tools and press the refresh icon (next to the save icon), it will show the latest DOM.

Example:

Go to script tab and do:

`document.body.appendChild( document.createElement("div") );`

Then go to the HTML tab and hit the refresh icon and open the body tag, it should show the appended div now.

Comment: Brilliant, embarrassed I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Firebug Lite - http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite (it's Firebug for IE, sort of)

Answer (score 0):

You should get [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). You can check the code that jQuery does and much more.

Anyway, I recommend that you put [Google Chrome Frame compatibility](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started) on your site, it will eliminate plenty of problems with your site (with the people that have Google Chrome Frame installed).